# How to routing between packages in workspace using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, yarnpkg, lerna

I'm using lerna and yarn workspace for my monorepo project. I already have a package name ProjectA using React. I want to create a landing page for this ProjectA package, which uses React, too.

I hope when I can deploy this project. The landing page use domain `landing.projecta.com` and the ProjectA use the domain `projecta.com`

But I don't know how to create a link on the landing page, which redirects to the main route of ProjectA. Can I use react-router for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the case described above, you should (IMHO) redirect just to the domain, as those 2 systems are (probably) supposed to be independent, right?

In case you do share the code in your packages, you could do something like below:

Using the packages structure below,

```
packages/
 - project-a
  - src/Home.jsx
 - landing
  - src/Home.jsx
```

You could use a function from `@your-scope/project-a` to create a full URL within `@your-scope/landing` sources.

```js
// landing/src/Home.jsx

import {getFullAppUrl} from '@your-scope/project-a/Home.jsx'

...
<Link to={{ pathname: getFullAppUrl() }}  target="_blank" />
...
```

```js
// project-a/src/Home.jsx

export function getFullAppUrl() {
   // your code here preparing the URL
}
```